# How to return array of string in function?

Tags: c, arrays, windows

I want to create a static array of string in a function , then the return value of this function will assign to another array of string .

but it seems I can't do this assignment `array2 = function();` but I think use `char *` for `array of string`    is ok? 
what's wrong in my code?
thanks

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * function();
int main(){

    char * array2[100] = {};
    array2 = function();

    // print this array of string
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(array2);i++){
        printf("%s\n",array2[i]);
    }
    system("pause");
}

char * function(){
    static char * array[100] = {};
    array[0] = "100";
    array[1] = "200";
    return array;
}
```

Comment: not sure if this is part of the problem, but you defined a prototype `funtion` before main but in main, you refer to `function`

Comment: you are returning static char* type but your function return type is char*

Comment: As noted by other comments, this code should not even compile.  What compiler are you using?  Is the compiler printing warnings when you build this code?  Do you have compiler warnings enabled at the maximum level?  You should check all of these first--then the compiler would practically solve this problem for you.

Comment: and if you want to assign the return type to some variable then that variable should also match the type. so in main function it should be static char *array2[]

Comment: Change `char ** funtion(){`  and try

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan static char ** funtion()

Comment: @Tonmoy: it doesn't have to be `static char **function()` just because the data it returns is `static`, which seems to be what you're suggesting.  You make a function `static` if you don't want it to be visible outside the source file (translation unit) in which it is defined.  That use of `static` is unrelated to its use in declaring a variable inside a function.  There `static` means that the variable has a lifetime as long as the program, not merely as long as the function call is in effect.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  if I do const char ** function() what does that mean? The function is const? or the function return type is const char** ?

Comment: There's no such thing as a 'const function' in C; that is a concept that applies to member functions in C++, but not to C.  The keywords `const`, `volatile` and `restrict` (and `_Atomic` in C11) are 'type qualifiers'; the keywords `static`, `extern`, `auto`, `register` (and, surprisingly, `typedef`, plus `_Thread_local` added in C11) are 'storage class specifiers'.  They do different jobs in the syntax.  In a declaration `const char **function();`, you specify that the function takes an indeterminate (not empty!) but fixed (not varargs) argument list and it returns a `const char **`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `char**` or `char* array[]` for array of strings.

In your `function()`, `array` is the first address of array of `char*`.the prototype should be `char **function()`.

And I don't think array's name can be changed.Say `int a[3], b[3];`, **`a` is a constant**, So `a = b` is not allowed.

Be careful about the spelling mistakes like `funtion()` `function()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                           
#include <stdlib.h>                                                          

static char **function(void)                                                 
{                                                                            
    char **array = malloc(2 * sizeof(*array));                               
    array[0] = "100";                                                        
    array[1] = "200";                                                        
    return array;                                                            
}                                                                            

int main(int argc, char *argv[])                                             
{                                                                            
    char **array2;                                                           
    array2 = function();                                                     

    /* print this array of string */                                         
    int i;                                                                   
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)                                                  
        printf("%s\n",array2[i]);                                            

    free(array2);                                                            

    return 0;                                                                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve your problem. It seems to be similar to these questions [general arrays][1]
[String arrays][2]

Or you can pass the array instead and get it working like this

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "string.h"

using namespace std;

void function(char *input[100]){
    input[0] = "100";
    input[1] = "200";
}
int main(){

    char * array2[100];
    function(array2);

    // print this array of string (int)strlen(*array2)
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<(int)strlen(*array2) - 1;i++){
        printf("%s\n",array2[i]);
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged C not C++, so `using namespace std;` is out of order; that's C++.  You should be consistent in using `#include <string.h>` rather than then the double-quoted form.  It isn't clear why you need `#include "stdafx.h"` since the code only used standard C functions.  The loop control on the `for` loop is broken; you should not be using `strlen()` there at all.

Comment: using namespace and stdafx is because of IDE. I just want to illustrate the point hence this code...I think the person who asked this question will get pointers to study more instead of complete answer. @JonathanLeffler can you please explain your point about strlen? how is it broken and is it exploitable?

Comment: You shouldn't let your IDE interfere with your code (but I'm prejudiced against IDEs in general, so treat with appropriate caution).  However, writing C++ code in answer to a C question is always going to get you into trouble.  The troubles with `strlen()` in context are that it returns 3 (because there are 3 digits in "100"), but there are only two strings to be printed (the other pointers are null). The length of the string `index[0]` is unrelated to the number of strings in the array. Even if it were the correct function to use, you'd not use it there.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler, I will keep your advice in mind. I will  to do some code writing to understand the exact behaviour of strlen, but thanks for pointing out